# iPhone 5 stuck at Apple boot logo after screen replacement

Tags: iphone, startup, screen, performance

My girlfriend smashed her iPhone screen. Being technically competent and after looking at YouTube videos of how to fix it I thought I would give it a go.

After replacing the screen and moving the front facing camera and speaker to the new screen I now get stuck on the Apple boot logo (hard resetting the phone doesn't help). I quickly then changed back to the old cracked glass screen without putting the front facing camera back and speaker and the phone booted up fine.

Therefore I presumed it was a faulty screen, so went to put the front facing camera back and speaker on the old cracked screen so that she can use it whilst a replacement arrives, but now the broken screen will only boot to the Apple logo screen.

- Is it possible that there is something with the camera or speaker preventing the phone from booting?
- Would restoring help as I can get into DFU mode?
- Is there anyway to debug this kind of issue?

Comment: I tried to restore but seems like no luck. I get to a waiting for iphone screen in iTunes then nothing happens.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem , with a customers phone the was heavily damaged around the camera area , have you tried using the new screen with out the camera ?

Comment: Yes, that is currently how the phone is being used and works without the camera. Was thinking if I replaced the camera this might fix it (just haven't got round to it)? Have you solved this issue yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue (under iOS 6) and i got it fixed with changing the whole part of the front camera!

hopely this will help you guys

Comment: I had actually bought the whole front camera to fit but just haven't got round to fitting it yet! Will update whether this was successful but sounding hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to try to back it up, then restore and see what happens from there. No idea why this would really happen. The restore will rule out iOS being bugged, and you'd know the issue purely lies with hardware.

Comment: Thanks, I tend to agree. I guess I was attempting to see if there would likely be an issue with restoring but I guess there's no real way no to know without trying.